# After migrating from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1, my web app got DependencyResolutionException of Autofac package

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to upgrade my web app from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 (the .net core 2.2 web app has no compile error or runtime error). But got the following runtime exception (The code can be built without compile error):

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An exception was thrown while activating Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSessionStore.
  Source=Autofac
  StackTrace:
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.CreateInstance(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.<StartAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at MyProject.Program.Main(String[] args) 

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSessionStore' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache cache' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)'.
```

The exception took place in Program.cs file:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //The exception happens here
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
 }
```

This is my Startup.cs file without confidential content:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        [Obsolete]
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            IConfigurationBuilder builder;
            if(env.EnvironmentName == "Development")
            {
                builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            }
            else
            {
                builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            }
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
        
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .AddFeatureFolders()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
            services.AddSession();

            //Database Context Configuration

            DisableCorrelationIdHeaders(services);

            #region Authentication
            //Authentication Settings
            #endregion


            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            //Email Settings



            //Swagger Configuration

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.Populate(services);
            builder.RegisterType<Mediator>().As<IMediator>();
            //Database Configuration

            var container = builder.Build();

            return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
        }


        [Obsolete]
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            //Routing Configuration
        }

        private void DisableCorrelationIdHeaders(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var module = services.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ImplementationFactory?.GetType() == typeof(Func<IServiceProvider, DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>));
            if (module != null)
            {
                services.Remove(module);
                services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryModule>(provider => new DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule { SetComponentCorrelationHttpHeaders = false });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my package settings in my Project.csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" Version="2.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="OdeToCode.AddFeatureFolders" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then I updated Autofac to 5.2.0 and updated Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection to 6.0.0. The same line code got the following runtime exceptions(The code can be built without compile error):

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An exception was thrown while activating Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSessionStore.
  Source=Autofac
  StackTrace:
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.CreateInstance(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.<StartAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at MyProject.Program.Main(String[] args) 

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSessionStore' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache cache' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)'.
```

How to fix the DependencyResolutionException? Do I need to change some codes in Startup.cs ? My project doesn't have Web.config. It uses appsettings.json.

Comment: It might be good to show your `Startup` class as well.

Comment: I will remove all sensitive code and post it

Comment: @Steven I have posted my Startup.cs

Comment: It says `Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache cache'`. I don't see a registration of `IDistributedCached` in your code. Is there an implicit registration somewhere hiding?

Comment: @alsami Yes you are right! Now the issue was resolved.